# Erc20 Token on Uniswap , sepolia testnet

Tags: sepolia

I'm trying to create Erc20 tradable tokens on Uniswap but I don't quite understand the full mechanism.

1.I created the erc20 token on sepolia test Eth network.

2. I created the pool on uniswap and added liquidity (token +sepolia Eth).
3. I can add and withdraw liquidity with the master address but if I swith to other account I cannot buy tokens.

Do I need to create a Uniswap v2 router contract?

Or where can I find some simple info regarding the mechanism behind it?